# how to post data into database through html template in django without using forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to post data into database through html template and render template successfully inserted into your database.but showing error

```
TypeError at /empdetails
'QueryDict' object is not callable
```

Here is my code models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    eno=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ename=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    eadd=models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and views.py

```
def Empdetails(request):
   num=request.POST('eno')
   nam=request.POST('ename')
   add=request.POST('eadd')
   details=Employee(eno=num,ename=nam,eadd=add)
   details.save()
   return render(request,'emp.html')
```

and template emp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/templates/inserted.html" method="post">
<label for="eno">Eid :</label>
<input type="text" name=" " value="" placeholder="eid" id="eno">
<label for="nam">Ename</label>
<input type="text" name=" " value="" placeholder="name" id="nam">
<label for="add">Eadd</label>
<input type="text" name=" " value="" placeholder="add" id="add">
<input type="submit" value="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing/logging the content of your `request.POST` object - are you sending data under the names you think you're sending them under? Your form has fields with names `ex.reddy`, `name` and `add` - but your view is looking for POST variables with names of `eno`, `ename`, and `eadd`.

The default behavior of `.get` is to return `None` when the provided key isn't present in the object, so if you're not actually sending an `eno` key then `request.POST.get('eno')` will be `None`.

That said, you're getting an `IntegrityError` when trying to save a null value to a field with `null=True`. Do you perhaps have any unapplied migrations?

Edit: addressing your edit, `querydict is not callable` means you're trying to use a dictionary like a function. `request.POST('thing')` cannot work - it should be `request.POST['thing']` or the .get syntax you had previously.

Edit: addressing your other edit, the names of your HTML form fields are all blank now. You should name these form fields with the `name`s under which you want to send the field values.

Comment: after changing the html template  name='' instead of name='ex.reddy'  again it's showing the IntegrityError at /empdetails
(1048, "Column 'eno' cannot be null")